# Is Code Concept an Appropriate Question for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Is it appropriate on stack overflow to ask questions more related around the concept of a coding language and how it should be be utilized, rather than directly asking a question about the coding problem you're having? For example, if you were going to make a program and you wanted to know what the best language/libraries would be for your specific idea, would it be okay to say what your goals with the program were, a bit of details on it, and what you really needed it to do?

In short; are coding concept questions appropriate on stack overflow, or does it need to be direct code bug Q&A?

Thanks, Nash.

Comment: It depends on the nature of the question. If the question's answers are subjective (e.g. "Is this the best method?"/"What is the best method?") then no, it is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's not really opinion based; more just a language's capability, so more of a fact. For example, if 3 languages can do what I need, I don't want someone to tell me why they think one is better than another. I'd just want them to name the three of them, as that would answer the question. Does that make sense?

Comment: P.S. In direct relation to your example, I would ask more to the point of 'What are the possible methods?' rather than what's the best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're describing two classes of questions that aren't a good fit for this site.

### First: You're asking for a resource recommendation.

> For example, if you were going to make a program and you wanted to know what the best language/libraries would be for your specific idea, would it be okay to say what your goals with the program were, a bit of details on it, and what you really needed it to do?

> For example, if 3 languages can do what I need, I don't want someone to tell me why they think one is better than another. I'd just want them to name the three of them, as that would answer the question.

If you want to know the libraries or languages available for a task, those aren't a good fit for our site. See the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) help page. It contains a list of questions not on topic, even if they're programming related. The fifth off-topic type of question is this one:

> 5. Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

That link leads to a meta discussion of resource recommendation questions.

### Second: You're asking for all the solutions to a problem.

> I would ask more to the point of 'What are the possible methods?' rather than what's the best.

Problematically, this is a bit open-ended. I imagine you don't want the bad or insane methods, and just want a practical solution to your problem. In that case, you should be requesting a solution, not a list of the methods available. List questions don't really work in our Q&A format anyway, so questions asking for a potentially infinite list often get closed.

## What you should ask instead

> For example, if you were going to make a program and you wanted to know what the best language/libraries would be for your specific idea, would it be okay to say what your goals with the program were, a bit of details on it, and what you really needed it to do?

So it sounds like you have a problem and want a solution. Great! That's what we're here for. Quoting [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask):

> You should only ask **practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face**. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Explain your situation and **ask for a solution** or **ask what your options are**.

The answer might describe a couple of alternatives either way, or there may be no alternatives. The answer might include a recommendation of a particular resource/library you'll want to use to help you get the job done.

However, either way, it's better than asking for a list of resources/libraries or a list of all possible methods. This just makes your question a pretty average and acceptable programming question, and we're totally OK with programming questions that aren't "my code is broke please fix it". Answers will just be solutions, and whether they include multiple options or resources is up to what it takes to answer the question.

But if all you're after is a resource recommendation or a list of methods, those won't be on topic or constructive either way.

Comment: Thanks, that answered a lot. When I said 'What are the possible methods?', that was just to make a point out of the example he had said.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be ok as long as the question is well detailed and clear and is about some architectural or design problem that a developer may face. It’s fairly easy to spot questions where the person asking has little idea about the topic and they’re trying to cut corners and get answers instead of trying to understand the problem themselves. This is opposed to people who thought through the problem and would like to get some more opinions before they make a decision themselves.

When a person asks those kind of questions it’s always better to show that they understand the problem and possible solutions (if there are any that come to mind). It should be directed towards one aspect of a problem/decision rather than a vague “which solution is better”. One could for instance ask: which solution would perform better? Or which one would be better for code maintainability?